# a href #section tag not working in safari

Tags: css, html, wordpress

The menu at the top on http://www.blackcoatinnovations.com the about and contact section are on the same page #third and #footer respectively. Those link work correctly in firefox as the `<a href"http://blackcoatinnovations.com/#third">` syntax was used in the menu but in safari on mac and ipad/iphone the page just refreshes.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am using the menu function of wordpress and funnily enough if I only write #third in the link instead of the full link, it does work! But I can't have that because then the menu would not work from the blog section of the website.

Comment: Adding `<div id="third"></div>` and `<div id="footer"></div>` just before the section tag (or inside it) should make it work.

Comment: You miss a `=` after `href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix here. You'll want to change the href to just "#third" and not the whole url.

`<a href="http://blackcoatinnovations.com/#third">`
becomes
`<a href="#third">`

When you write http inside of the url, this is actually telling the browser that you are directing it to a new domain. Since you want to stay on your own domain, you remove the http and the domain itself because you want to open up (a) the index (that '/') and (b) you want to go to a single portion (being the '#third').

I hope you understand why you don't need the http://blackcoatinnovations.com/ beginning now.